# mvc4 how to make a function in controller with null able parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a login form and if the user enter correct login information,he/she will go into my website.

However, if he/she enters not correct information, i want to return him to the same page that he/she enters his/her information with the fields filed in already.

I mean, i want to the page where he could see his/her username and password that he/she has entered in the fields, not to start typing from the zero.

I tried that

```
public ActionResult(Login ?login = null){}
```

so i call this function when i want to show the login page with null parameter. and i call it when the user enters a not correct informatoin. However, i go exception

> The type 'Login' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

have you help me in this problem please?

#### if there is second solution tell me, but please not about member ship and these guys because i have my own way to asure the users

#### Edit

when the user press on login button, i go to this controller function

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

when he submit his/her form in login page i go to this function

```
public ActionResult Login(Login login) {}
```

i want in the `login` function above, if the user enters not correct informatoin to return to the `index` page where he/she saw the data that he/she has submitted

Comment: "Login" seems to be a class so it's already nullable

Comment: @jim `login` is my model class in model forlder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use this:

```
// [HttpPost] and any other attributes necessary
public ActionResult YourAction(Login login)
{
    ...
}
```

But considering general idea of the logic you want to achieve, I would say that you don't need the login to be null.

The action just does what it does: it processes the login (after a postback done on client part). So, it always must contain any data.

If you want to redirect after some checks of login info, you receive them, check and then do `RedirectToAction(...)` or any other type of redirection you want.

Then in view you would have (for Index action, for instance):

```
@model Login

@using(Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "home"))
{
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)

        <input type="submit" value="go"/>              
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Just imagine that your YourAction is Login:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    // this one is called on the first entering of login and shows the form to fill
    return View(new Login()); // for instance
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Login login)
{
    // this one is called on PostBack after filling the form and pressing 'Login' (or something) button
    // todo:  here you to validate the login info
    // and then either do your redirect to some other page or showing the login form again

    // if(something)
    //    return RedirectToAction(...);

    return View(login);
}
```

Comment: but in your way when the user first ask for the login page, it shows with the error message that his infroation is not correct

Comment: Login page must be created with another action: for instance, `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Login()` without any parameters and for GET HTTP method. Then you render some form, which would send the postback to YourAction (might be also Login one (another method), but with a parameter and a POST HTTP method).

Comment: in your edit answer you said this `either do your redirect to some other page or showing the login` so what should i code to redirect to my page that contains the already fieled filds?

Comment: all the majec comes from making the two methos as the same name

Comment: Yes. And don't forget to use Post/Get specification attributes to prevent diffirent negative situations.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new MVC Internet application (a VS template) and see how "Model.IsValid" is used inside controllers. This is the most common approach. When some model comes into controller, you check if it's valid (redirect to Homepage or whatever), otherwise you just show the same view providing it with this model that is already (partially) poplated by user.
This is the one:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do things
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Model errors can occur during implicit model binding (say if some required properties not present in incoming data) or be set explicitly in the code by using of ModelState.AddModelError. Putting html validators on the page makes user know what kind of constraints are applied to the field value.

Comment: what is returneURL? please?

Comment: @user2208349 when you use FormAuthentication mechanism (ASP.NET integrated) you specify Login page url in web.config file (search for "loginUrl" string). When anonymous user tries to open url that is only allowed for authenticated users (see "AuthorizationAttribute") then server automatically redirects user to specified login page. By default its url is ~/Account/LogOn (see web.config) and in terms of MVC routing this means Account controller, LogOn action.

Comment: @user2208349 ...When redirecting, server also adds an extra parameter - returnUrl so your controller action can know the initially accessed page Url and is able to redirect user back in case of successfull login.

Comment: that is compeletely not my qestion, i want to return to the login page with information already field in when the users enters not correct informaton

Comment: @user2208349 the answer to THIS question is above comments. My comments were about "what is returneURL". Create a new default MVC Internet Application and see how things like you want are done.

Comment: @user2208349 the cycle: 1. user enters information and pushes button 2. Values go to server and are bound to view model 3. Controller action tests if view model is OK or not 4. If not, return the same login view supplied with model that came from user.

Comment: As Index action doesnt have params so you aren't able to pass any data into there (im not talking of controller-scoped variables), but the Login action canreturn any view you want with the incorrect user's data. I would use Login() and [HttpPost]Login(Login login) actions.

Comment: +1 to you, i apprecitae your help and support and efforst, and really i am sorry cos i can't select just one answer, i really thank you very very very very very much and please forgive me to not select ur answer, i loke you